# flash builder 4.5, 64 bit version download

Tags: flash-builder4.5

Can anybody share the link for Flash builder 4.5, 64 bit version.
because of some Graphs issues I cannot use Flex 4.6 and flash builder 4.7 don't support the design view. I tried the Adobe official site but FB 4.7 is available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 64 Bit version of Flash Builder 4.5.

Flash Builder 4.7 was the first and is currently the only version that is available as 32 and 64 Bit edition.

You could take a look at IntelliJ IDEA which is available as a 64 Bit version and [supports Flex and has a design view](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/flex_ide.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks Gerhard. In that case I will switch to 32 bit combination for JDK, Eclipse and Flash builder. My windows 7 OS is 64 bit.